# Run a local http(s) proxy from command line using built-in commands

Tags: terminal, network, command-line, proxy, http

We've been using Charles Proxy during the development of a product, but now need to be able to script/automate the same behaviour using command line tools on macOS.

My understanding is that Charles Proxy is effectively a UI on top of system level tools. We don't need the UI - just the underlying proxying capability (including SSL proxying).

Does anyone know if it is possible to run a local proxy server, supporting SSL proxying, from the command line on macOS, ideally using only built-in shell commands?

If that's not possible, `brew install`-able tools would be a next best, but we need to absolutely minimise dependencies.

Comment: Please check https://mitmproxy.org/ (Installation is done with `brew install mitmproxy`)...